# Use Case : Kafka Single Topic with volume of subscribers

Tags: apache-kafka

Scenario: A third party system produces messages for specific users and sents to a middleware system. The middleware system processes the messages and stores these messages in a Kafka topic named "MessageTopic". Now at the other end, there are 1000 or 10,000 growing users + which have subscribed to the topic for receiving the messages.

Now, each message is intended for a specific user.And so the expectation is that each user must receive only that specific message ?

Can you please let know how it can be achieved using Kafka topic? [Obviously creating thousands of topics would not make sense in this case.]

Comment: I think this is XY problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem
You should describe your original problem. I haven't seen any requirements that need separate queue for each user.

Comment: How many messages do you expect per user per minute for example? What do you call a user, it's probably a specific system that should consume the messages that have been sent for it? Each message has to be consumed by one and only one consumer? Will you have more than one instance of a given consumer/user?

Comment: @pgras : Number of messages per user would vary. On a average say, 25 messages per hour for a user. And yes, a user is a system subscribed to the kafka topic. The messages would land in that topic for different users but each message is intended for only one user and should be consumed by that user only. Overall there would be thousands of users(consumers) but each user would be unique.

Comment: if the number of users are fixed then we can create Kafka topic with that many number of partitions (partition per user) and read and write to that specific partition. but if the number of users are dynamic then we can have one single consumer program that read all the data and filter the data and route to respective user based on the data.

Comment: @SureshChaganti : The number of users can increase or decrease down the line. Would that problematic as far as Kafka partitions are concerned ? Secondly, how does each of the user[say user1,user2,....usern) gets correlated to its specific partition?. For your explanation on dynamic users, not sure by what mechanism can the data be routed to respective user?

Comment: How does a consumer knows a given message is for him? And/or does the publisher knows which consumer has to consume one given message? (Does the message contain the information "I should be read by user ABC?")

Comment: @ValBonn : yes the message would contain some kind of identifier for each user